# Problem changing the color of a cell partially with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, richtext, custom-function

I need to put 2 rows of data in a single cell, and color code them like so:
[endgoal][image: 1]

So I decided to make a custom function with apps script, so far i've only been able to make the text be on top of each other, but can't for the life of me make it change color, so I was hoping to get some help here.

The function I made is the following (it's extremely simple but i'm a noob)

```
function pileUp(val1,val2) {
  return val1+"\n"+val2
}
```

I've been searching here and found some people partially coloring cells, but none I tried worked for me, would appreciate any help.

*P.D: The length of both bottom and top rows varies cell by cell, so anything that uses a range with a fixed amount of characters to color won't work*

*P.D.2: I do realize I didn't post my approach to actually changing the color, here it is:*

```
function pileUp(val1,val2) {   
  var color="#b82f2f";   
  var format =SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
    .setForegroundColor(color)
    .build();
  var final=SpreadsheetApp
    .newRichTextValue()
    .setText('val1"\n"+val2')
    .setTextStyle(0, 3, format);     
return final }
```

I intended to see if this worked, then change the 3 in the penultimate line for a variable that was equal to the length of var1, but it didn't work.

Comment: You do that with richText

Comment: @Cooper Yeah I know, but haven't been able to get it to work. 
What I figured would work was something like:
`function pileUp(val1,val2) {
  var color="#b82f2f";
  var format = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor(color).build();
  var final=SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText('val1"\n"+val2').setTextStyle(0, 3, format);  
  return final
}`
But it did't work and i'm stuck.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, RichText cannot be used in the custom function. In this case, what do you want to do?

Comment: A custom function can only [return simple values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#return_values), and it cannot use other methods to write to cells (`set*()`). Is it necessary to use a custom function?

Comment: @Tanaike Damn :/ so the custom function is a dead end, I hoped so hard that te custom function would work. What I need is the cell to look like the cell in the picture I posted in my original post, coloring just the text on the bottom. No, it doesn't need to be a custom function, any way that I can automatically color the bottom of the 2 values works for me. The function thing was just my approach. What way do you guys think it can work? With the bottom row size of the text being variable cell by cell.

Comment: Use onEdit or menu item click.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that your goal includes the method for executing the script without using the custom function. By this, I propsoed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You have the values like `sample1\nsample2` in the cells. In this case, 2 lines are existing in a cell.
- You want to change the text style of the 2nd line to the font color of `#b82f2f`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script. In this case, you can directly run the script without using the custom function.

In this case, how about the following sample scripts?

#### Sample script 1:

In this case, the script can be run from the custom menu. When you reopened Spreadsheet, the custom menu is created by OnOpen trigger.

When you use this script, please select the cell and run the script from the custom menu. By this, the script works.

```js
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("sample").addItem("Run script", "myFunction").addToUi();
}

function myFunction() {
  var color = "#b82f2f"; // This is from your script.

  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  const format = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor(color).build();
  const v = range.getRichTextValues().map(r =>
    r.map(c => {
      const delimiter = "\n";
      const text = c.getText();
      const idx = text.indexOf(delimiter);
      if (idx != -1) {
        const temp = text.split(delimiter);
        return c.copy().setTextStyle(idx, idx + delimiter.length + temp[1].length, format).build();
      }
      return c;
    })
  );
  range.setRichTextValues(v);
}
```

#### Sample script 2:

In this case, by giving the variables of `rangeA1Notation` and `sheetName`, you can directly run the script with the script editor.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const rangeA1Notation = "A1:A3"; // Please set the cell range as A1Notation.
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const color = "#b82f2f"; // This is from your script.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  const format = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor(color).build();
  const v = range.getRichTextValues().map(r =>
    r.map(c => {
      const delimiter = "\n";
      const text = c.getText();
      const idx = text.indexOf(delimiter);
      if (idx != -1) {
        const temp = text.split(delimiter);
        return c.copy().setTextStyle(idx, idx + delimiter.length + temp[1].length, format).build();
      }
      return c;
    })
  );
  range.setRichTextValues(v);
}
```

#### References:

- [getRichTextValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrichtextvalues)
- [setRichTextValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluesvalues)
- [Class RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value)

Comment: Sorry  that I didn't respond earlier. 

I just checked you answer and used the Sample Script 2 you provided, it works like a charm, thanks a lot for your help and for even providing 2 different ways of doing it. The only problem with it is that it wipes cells that don't have the format `value1\nvalue2`, and it sometimes happens that there's not a value to update and a cell might end up with just 1 value. I'll try to fix this myself as I think it can be fixed with just an IF, but if I can't pull it off, I'll post another comment.

Thanks a lot, regards,
Helios.

Comment: @helios paniagua Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.